# MySQL Column in HTML Select

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

I am trying to populate an html select statement with data from a column in a SQL table. The following is the code I am trying to use. The problem is that nothing from my SQL table shows up in my html select.

```
<p>
    <select name="animal_Groups">
    <?php

        $con = mysqli_connect("SERVER1","t_user","passwordsAreFun","t_dev");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT [Group] FROM All_Animals");

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            // echo '<option value="'. $row['value'] .'">'. $row['name'] .'</option>';
            echo '<option value="'. $row['value'] .'">'. $row['value'] .'</option>';
        }

        mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
    </select>
</p>
```

Thank you for looking and answers!!! The output that is generated is an empty html select option. It expands but has nothing filling it.[image]

Here is a shot of my sql table (it was originally imported from an Access DB)[image]:

Comment: Can you please add the output which is generated?

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,name FROM All_Animals");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo '<option value="'. $row['id'] .'">'. $row['name'] .'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response sbrbot. So my sql table does not have an id column. It is simply just Group and Common Name and I want the Group to be displayed.Because Group is a key work in sql I have to put it in brackets so that sql knows it is a table column and not a key work right? Does this effect how I should fix my statement.

Comment: You don't use brackets to wrap the word `Group`, you use backticks ` that little character over to the left of the number `1-!` on your keyboard. @visualbasicNoob9000

Comment: Thanks for the reply Fred. I changed the [Group] to `Group` but my problem still persists. The select statement is coming up blank.

Comment: GROUP is reserved word in SQL so use SELECT \`Group\` FROM \`All_Animals\`